# iOS -Whats' the difference between pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK' and pod 'Firebase/AdMob'

Tags: ios, firebase, admob, cocoapods

I want to add adMob to my iOS apps. I already have a firebase project created and the `GoogleService-Info.plist` is already imported inside my project.

When adding the adMob pod what's the difference or better yet the pros and cons between using `pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'` and `pod 'Firebase/AdMob'` for an already existing firebase project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that `pod 'Firebase/AdMob'` will also include the FirebaseCore pod and the Firebase.h headers. See the Admob subspec definition in the [Firebase subspec](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.6.0/Firebase.podspec.json#L325).

If there are already other Firebase pods in the Podfile, there will be no difference to what gets installed.

Comment: I already have the Firebase/Core pod from when I previously installed all the other Firebase pods. Sounds like other then that they do the same exact things?

Comment: Yep. No effective difference.

Comment: Ok thanks, it won't let me accept you answer for another 9 minutes

Comment: I do have another question if you don;'t mind. I was watching some videos on installing it and everyone in the videos seemed to add adMob to the firebase project beforehand and when they downloaded their googleservice-info.plist there were 2 fields for adMob: Ad_Unit_Id_For_Banner_Test and Ad_Unit_Id_For_Interstital_Test. Since my googleservice-info.plist was created before I added in adMob, do i need to generate a new googleservice-info.plist ?

Comment: After I added in the Firebase/AdMob pod I checked the google service.plist and they aren’t there.

Comment: Hmm, if they're not there, it's likely because they're no longer used. The contents of GoogleService-Info.plist comes from the console without any connection to what's in the Podfile.

Comment: I just linked my app with admob and was given a new plist. It doesn’t contain those but it does contain a field named “ADMOB_APP_ID” with my AD ID as the value. Maybe the new ask doesn’t use those anymore and just uses this? Btw everything else in the new plist was the same as the old plist except it has this new field